# Is it possible to integrate Arc GIS with Azure Data Factory or Azure Events Hub?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, arcgis, azure-eventhub

I am having a requirement to integrate Arc GIS application and Azure including location-based data collected from Arc GIS application into data warehouse. Are there any possibilities to use Azure Data Factory pipelines or Azure Events Hub to extract the data from Arc GIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, so far Azure Data Factory doesn't have a connector to integrate with ArcGIS. Please visit the [ADF Connectors Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview#supported-data-stores) to know more about the available supported data stores.

As far as Azure Eventhub integration with ArcGIS, as per this official [document](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/iot/ingest/azure-event-hub.htm), Azure Event Hub can be used as a central message hub for bi-directional communication between ArcGIS Velocity and your IoT devices.